# Why doesn't the exception quit the program?

Tags: c++, exception, mingw, clion

This is my custom exception:

```
class MyException {
public:
    MyException()
            :message("..."){}
    const char *what() const {return message;}
private:
    const char * message;
};
```

This is the class:

```
Class MyClass {
    void function() {
        // [...]
        if (condition) throw MyException();
        // [...]
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
MyClass a;
try {
    a.function();
}
catch (MyException & ex) {
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

I thought that the program was going to quit if `condition == true`, but instead it proceeds... Why? (The message is regularly displayed)

P.S.

The same if I do something like:

```
function2();

int main {
    function2();
}

function2() {
    try {
        // something that may create an exception
    }
    catch (MyException & ex) {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only an uncatched exception terminates the program. The whole point of `catch` is to prevent the termination.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't get it at all! What's their meaning then? Does it "interrupt" the function at least? (forgive my ignorance)

Comment: @JohnBardeen When a function encounters a `throw` it immediately ends the function (as-if it was `return`ed from, but without a result). It then does the same thing with the calling function. Then, from the function that called that function. If this would go on until `main` it terminate instead. This cascade is interrupted if any of these function calls where made from a `try` block that has a `catch` that matches the type of exception that was thrown. It jumps to that `catch` block and resumes normally from there.

Comment: The code that was in the `try` block is interrupted. It stops dead, anything local to the `try` block goes out of scope and is destroyed, and the program picks up at the `catch`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, very clear explanations!

Comment: Note that dynamic allocations and other resources will only be destroyed/freed if they are [protected by RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). Throwing exceptions is a great way to spring a leak if you're not very careful

Comment: I'm using smart pointers (`shared_ptr` in particular)... Is that enough to avoid leaks?

Comment: A `throw`/`catch` is an invisible `goto` for exceptional situations.  In my previous project, a `throw` was tantamount to "panic save work-in-progress, and quit the application".  In my current project, exceptions are used with a plethora of conventions.

Comment: `shared_ptr` sill requires a certain amount of care to use. For example, do not allow cycles. Note that shared ownership is pretty uncommon. Most of the time a `unique_ptr`does everything you need with noticeably less overhead.

Comment: I used shared_ptr because I needed to copy the pointers... Do you find it a sufficient reason?

Comment: Shared pointer's not about copying. You can do that with a plain old raw pointer. It's about who is responsible for managing and releasing a resource.  If you have a pointer that is only used in the same broad scope, a `unique_ptr` at the base of that scope is sufficient. It''ll be destroyed when the call stack pops its way back down. Pass it by reference or a s a raw pointer up the stack. If you need to send it down the stack, you can probably move it and transfer ownership.

Comment: If you have multiple threads that all depend on the resource and don't have a central coordinating point that will outlive all of the threads and has an ownership stake in the life of the resource, that's a good case for a `shared_ptr` because you no longer know when the resource will be released. It needs to remain until all of the users are gone, and when that will be is hard to predict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You caught the exception that is why the program didn't crash. The point of exception handling is to catch exceptions and handle them gracefully.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't get it at all! What should I do then?

Comment: Rethrow it in your handler?

Comment: @PaulSanders Generally that means you shouldn't have caught the exception in the first place.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes. I don't actually know what the OP is trying to achieve...

Comment: @JohnBardeen you do what needs to be done based on the exception. If the program needs to terminate then you should do that. It really depends on what went wrong and what that means for your program

Comment: My function is actually a bool function... If the exception occurs I can't get the right value I needed...

Comment: Can/should the program continue if this happens?

Comment: If you so then use that catch block to update what you need to update. If not then you should return 1 and exit the program

Comment: You need to decide whether to handle error conditions by using exceptions or by using return codes. That seems to be the issue here.

Comment: I used the catch block to do what I need, thank you!